# Why do I keep getting illegal address error?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am currently trying to implement the Gmail API to send email to a group of addresses along with an attachment file.

*My code to implement the Gmail API is as follows:*

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public GMailSender() {
    if (rb1 != null && rad.isChecked()){
        message=s1;
    }else if(rb1 != null && rad1.isChecked())
    {
        message=item;
    }
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = "abhishek.roychoudhury69@gmail.com"; // username
    _pass = "abhishekcena"; // password
    _from = "abhishek.roychoudhury69@gmail.com"; // email sent from
    _subject = s3; // email subject
    _body = message; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public GMailSender(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        // msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);
        Log.d("The message is:", String.valueOf(msg));

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if(_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if(_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._to=toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._from=string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this._subject=string;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
```

}

*The code for calling the GmailSender function from another activity:*

```
 GMailSender m = new GMailSender("abhishek.roychoudhury69@gmail.com", "abhishekcena");

    s4=editText.getText().toString();
    String[] toArr = {s4}; //s4 is the edittext.getText().toString() field.
    m.setTo(toArr);
    m.setFrom("abhishek.roychoudhury69@gmail.com");
    m.setSubject(s3);
    m.setBody(message);
    for (int i = 0; i < toArr.length; i++) {
        try {
            m.addAttachment(path);

            if (m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that suppose I type in 2 email ids (eg: "xyz@abc.co.in, acb.123@gmail.com") into my editText field `s4`, I get an error in this format:

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``xyz@abc.co.in, acb.123@gmail.com''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:108)
```

But if I give those same emails as parameters to my `toArr[]` (i.e., `toArr[]={"xyz@abc.co.in, acb.123@gmail.com"`}), the email gets sent. Why?

Comment: `acb@123@gmail.com` is an invalid email address. There can only be one `@` in an address, unless quoted. e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part

Comment: The two emails I've given are just for examples. This problem occurs with any email you give. (acb.123@gmail.com sorry for the typing mistake :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark Rotteveel said, the setTo() method was taking the whole textfield as an array. What I did was, I first splitted the email textfield based on the "," symbol. After that I put each of the value of the splitted array into another array and set that as a parameter to the setTo() method. As a result, now its taking each individual email id as a single array.

```
 String splitedemail[]=new String[5];
 for(int i=0;i<splitedemail.length;i++) {
                s4 = text3.getText().toString();
                splitedemail=s4.split(",");
            }
 for( i=0;i<splitedemail.length;i++) {
        toArr[i] = splitedemail[i]; 
        String arr[] = {toArr[i]};
        m.setTo(arr);
        m.setFrom("abhishek.roychoudhury69@gmail.com");
        m.setSubject(s3);
        m.setBody(message);

        try {
            m.addAttachment(path);

            if (m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setTo method is expecting an array of strings, with each string containing only a single email address.

If you want to allow multiple email addresses to be entered in a single text field, and thus appear in a single string, change your setTo method to take a single String, then use that String in the [MimeMessage.setRecipients](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setRecipients-javax.mail.Message.RecipientType-java.lang.String-) method.

While you're in there cleaning up this code you copied from somewhere else, you should also fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Isn't `{"xyz@abc.co.in, acb.123@gmail.com"}` an array of strings? Here setTo method is taking an array of Strings, and I am also giving an array of strings as input. Then why isn't it accepting it?

Comment: @Parker That is an array with **one** string, which parses to an invalid address. If you want to parse multiple addresses, then you should use `{"xyz@abc.co.in", "acb.123@gmail.com"}`. Or look at using [`InternetAddress.parse(String)`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I tried using `InternetAddress.parse(s4)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Parker "It doesn't work" gives us zero information to help you.

Comment: by "it doesn't work" I mean that I am getting the same error (`Illegal address in String...`)

Comment: Did you try MimeMessage.setRecipients?  If it's still not working, post your updated code.  The code in your answer below is completely wrong.